# Why accuracy manually calculated by model.predict() is different from model.evaluate()'s accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

The accuracy calculated using the predicted labels and the true labels is particularly low, is there something I've written wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your data will be randomly shuffled two times.

1. The first one is when you call `modified.predict(test_data)`. The `test_data` iterator will randomly shuffle the data.
2. When you manually iterate over your dataset:
   `for images, labels in test_data`
   The data will also be randomly shuffled. So the labels order will different from the one you got with `model.predict()`.

It is a default behavior of the dataset created with `image_dataset_from_directory` function.
You can check the documentation and default values of different arguments here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory

If you set the `shuffle=False`:

```
test_data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir + '/test',
    image_size=(32, 32),
    batch_size=train_batch_size,
    shuffle=False,
)
```

the manually calculated results and `model.predict()`ed ones will be identical (at least in the case of `accuracy` metric because evaluate aggregate the metrics over batches that could lead to the differences in the case of some other metrics).

Comment: For point two: How to I stop this behaviour?